# Are Flask sessions unique to each ip?

Tags: python, flask

Is the Flask session object based on the ip address of the user/request?  How does it actually allow each user to have their own session?  Is it ideal to allow a user to login from many devices or is that risky as far as user experience vs security?

Comment: The sessions are cookie based and not related to IP, just like sessions in more or less any web framework. No need to worry about multiple devices.

Comment: thanks! so is there a default timeout of the cookie? if not, how do i define one? is it client side cookie or server side session?

Comment: Most of this stuff is in the docs. Try it out, if you have specific questions, post those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions in Flask are cookie-based, meaning that is not necessarily IP/user/request based unless you develop the server logic in this way. The fact that sessions are cookies based allows the user to read the content, so be aware of what you put there. Anyway, the user can't easily modify the content because it is ciphered on the server-side.

A simple example is present in the Flask documentation [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#sessions).
Remember that sessions are global and thread-safe Flask variables.
Further details about sessions can be found [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#sessions).

If it is the ideal way or not of allowing users to log in from many devices, that depends on your needs. In my opinion, it makes a web application more versatile.

If it is risky or not, depends on how well the system was developed. Just take the GMail or any Google application as an example. You can handle many sessions from many devices still being secure.

FROM @pvg WARNING AND SOME RESEARCHES:
If you want to store sensitive information and using a DB is overkilling, server-side sessions it's a better choice. Take a look at [this article](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-secure-is-the-flask-user-session).

Comment: There is an important difference between the session security of Gmail or Google apps (or really, most web apps these days) in that they do not send the actual session data clientside. The default Flask session implementation is designed for convenience (i.e. no need to install a separate session store) but is not suitable for applications in which security is a substantial concern.

Comment: Thanks, That explains a lot!

Comment: @pvg can you send us information to check why the flask session is securely weak for applications where security is a substantial concern? I'm interesting on that, thanks.

Comment: @pvg did you refere to server-side sessions? I added it to the answer.